# selenium grid parallel execution configuration

Tags: selenium

How to configure multiple nodes from a single machine.I want to write code for congifuration from a single virtual machine ,no need to go to each virtual machine and start hub nd node there.In another word,Ii want to run parallel execution of 10 virtual machine and want to configure for a single hub nd from single machine.help me.urgent

Answer (score 0):

I think u can do it by configuring hub and node in the same machine but giving dfferent Port No's like 5566,5555 etc. i have not tried it, but give it a try

Comment: I would suggest you to go through this link-

http://www.guru99.com/introduction-to-selenium-grid.html